# How to call sidekiq perform fuction after every five minutes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq, daemons, sidekiq-cron

```
require 'sidekiq'

module KYC
  module VerifyInvestor
    class AccreditedVerificationWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker
       
      def perform()
        ....
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sidekiq Enterprise has this feature: https://sidekiq.org/products/enterprise.html. There are free plugins too. A few years ago I used [Sidetiq](https://github.com/endofunky/sidetiq), but it's is abandoned now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For free solution you can use [sidekiq-cron gem](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron) and create a cron job from console to run every 5 minutes:

```
Sidekiq::Cron::Job.create(name: 'AccreditedVerificationWorker - every 5min', cron: '*/5 * * * *', class: 'KYC::VerifyInvestor::AccreditedVerificationWorker')
```